# using WMI to Monitor file/folder creation event

Tags: wmi

```
SELECT * 
FROM __InstanceCreationEvent WITHIN 5 
WHERE TargetInstance ISA 'CIM_DataFile' 
    AND TargetInstance.Drive = 'C:'
```

i have a code to monitor changes in c drive 
but i need to monitor all drives in the computer

Comment: and i need to folders also this only monitors files using c++

Comment: If select statement is all there is to it, maybe you should not specify the drive? `SELECT * 
FROM __InstanceCreationEvent WITHIN 5 
WHERE TargetInstance ISA 'CIM_DataFile'`

Comment: i have tried it but it says quota violation